# How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and replace the value of the previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays containing timestamp and it's value.

I'm using these data to generate charts using HighCharts plugin.

```
  array_1 is my default
  array_2 is my dynamic data
```

Here's my helper method that generates default data.

```
def default_chart_data
  data = []
  d = local_time_here
  for hour in 0..23 do
    data << [d.change(hour: hour, min: 0, sec: 0).to_i * 1000, rand(5..500)]
  end
  return data
end
```

My aim is to **replace** the values of my default array with my **dynamic** values based on **timestamp** as key,

and, **ADDs** the other data that it's not present in default array `array1`

And finally sort it once merged.

```
  For example:

  var array1 =  [
    [1561867200000, 0],
    [1561870800000, 0], // value should change to 2
    [1561874400000, 0],
    [1561878000000, 0],
    [1561881600000, 0], // value should change to 5
  ]


  var array2 =  [
    [1561867200000, 1],
    [1561870800000, 2], // 1st matched from array1
    [1561874400000, 3],
    [1561878000000, 4],
    [1561881600000, 5], // 2nd matched from array1  
    [1561921200000, 6]
  ]



  Expected Result like, once merged:

  [
    [1561870800000, 2],
    [1561867200000, 1],
    [1561874400000, 3],
    [1561878000000, 4],
    [1561881600000, 5],
    [1561921200000, 6]
  ].sort_based_on_timestamp_here(how?)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the integer? Is it necessary to your cause? Are the timestamps supposed to be unique?

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, the format is at it is, i used it for highcharts, thus timestamp should be unique

Comment: It should just *replace*, not *add*, correct? (just looks like it b/c 2 + 0 = 2 and 5 + 0 = 5).

Comment: @JackBashford oops... my question is wrong, it should replace and add if not exists in default array, i'll update my Q

Comment: Okay, so if the values `1` and `3` are matched in the first and second array respectively, should the final value be `3` (replace from second) or `4` (add both together)?

Comment: @JackBashford the values from the array2 should replace the values of array1

Comment: Umm...I don't get why there are duplicates in the expected output. *All* of the values in the first array match...so you'd only get an array as long as the first or second array for any combination. How'd you only get 5 and 2 to match, and such a long result with duplicates?

Comment: My first question comes back to light! Thanks Jack.

Comment: Do you have any code? You've given us an input and a desired output with nothing in between. It kinda sounds like you're just asking us to write this whole thing for you. There are plenty of other questions on StackOverflow about merging arrays that should at least get you started with an attempt.

Comment: Your description and expected result are not matched. `1561867200000` is also existed in the second array with value 1.

Comment: sorry, my bad pasting the expected result, there should be no more duplicates on it.

Comment: So, your question is sorting? or merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.

First we [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) array1 to get values that are not in array2.

Then we join using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the defaults to array2.

Then we [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the final array.

```js
  var array1 =  [
    [1561867200000, 0],
    [1561870800000, 0], // value should change to 2
    [1561874400000, 0],
    [1561878000000, 0],
    [1561881600000, 0], // value should change to 5
  ]


  var array2 =  [
    [1561867200000, 1],
    [1561870800000, 2], // 1st matched from array1
    [1561874400000, 3],
    [1561878000000, 4],
    [1561881600000, 5], // 2nd matched from array1  
    [1561921200000, 6]
  ]

var defaults = array1.filter(arr1 => !array2.find(arr2 => arr2[0] === arr1[0]))
var all = defaults.concat(array2)
var sorted = all.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0])
console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as [@BlueWater86](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3236706/bluewater86)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829428/5901282) (and also a little hazy on the question) but shouldn't require sorting if both arrays are already in order:

```
  var array1 =  [
    [1561867200000, 0],
    [1561870800000, 0], // value should change to 2
    [1561874400000, 0],
    [1561878000000, 0],
    [1561881600000, 0], // value should change to 5
  ]


  var array2 =  [
    [1561867200000, 1],
    [1561870800000, 2], // 1st matched from array1
    [1561874400000, 3],
    [1561878000000, 4],
    [1561881600000, 5], // 2nd matched from array1
    [1561921200000, 6]
  ]


var result = [];

for( var index1 = 0; index1 < array1.length; index1++ ) {
    var item1 = array1[index1];

    for( var index2 = array2.length - 1; index2 >= 0; index2-- ) {
        var item2 = array2[index2];
        if(item1[0] === item2[0]) {
            result.push(item2);
            array2.splice(index2, 1);
            break;
        }

        if(index2 != 0)
            continue;
        result.push(item2);
    }
}
for( var index2 = array2.length - 1; index2 >= 0; index2-- ) {
        result.push(array2[index2]);
}

console.log(result);
```

By reversing through the second array when we add them elements, that should keep the order correct.